# How can I disrupt a rift without getting interrupted?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Disrupting a rift seems like a useful thing, and the game strongly points me towards doing that regularly. But apart from the first fight in the prologue where you can disrupt a rift, I can't seem to make good use of the ability.

The main problem is that I get interrupted by enemy attacks almost every time I try to disrupt a rift. This aborts the disruption process and I've achieved nothing at all by trying.

Is there any way to prevent getting interrupted by enemy attacks when disrupting a rift?

Comment: Seems enemies are aware of what you're up to when you try to disrupt the rift and will shift their aggression to you.  Not sure what tools are available for aggro control.  The only thing I've found partially effective so far is trying to have some cover (rocks/elevation shifts) between you and any shooters in the group, or dealing with the shooters first before disrupting the rift.  I haven't figured out how to keep melee thugs tangled up.  So that's half an answer for you.

Comment: I don't really have a general purpose solution right now (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), but Rogues can use Stealth to drop enemy aggro and then disrupt the rift without being interrupted.

Answer (score 5):

Try to hang back a bit while your tank (or other characters) start attacking, so they grab the enemy's attention (aggro). Your warrior tank should have abilities like Challenge and War Cry - that'll definitely get their attention off you.

I'm playing a mage myself. When attacking a rift, I switch to my warrior or any of the other characters and simply use them to launch the first few attacks. Then switch back, and you shouldn't have aggro.

Like someone noted in the comments - it does seem that enemies who are currently *not* attacking you, but have not been aggroed by anyone (e.g. not attacked, or taunted), *will* shift their focus to you once you start disrupting. The only way to solve this is by focusing it down, or by taunting it with your tank.

Also, I've noticed that, when using a different party member, the option to Disrupt Rift also appears - but I haven't actually tried that, so I don't know what happens.

Comment: nothing! it says cant use, need the inquisitor or some such if you try closing the rift with a companion.

Answer (score -4):

What I do is kill everything that comes out of the rifts! Free XP and after you kill the 3-4 waves of enemies out of a rift it is down to 2-5% healts anyway so I just do it then and avoid being interrupted!

Who doesn't like Free XP???

Did the same thing in the Fallow mire around the castle. Companions kept shouting to run into the sastle but I stayed and killed everything that came at me. got tons and tons of XP doint that. :-P

Comment: Disrupting rifts doesn't make fewer enemies come out, it just stuns the ones that are already present.

Comment: I never said fewer enemies. I just don't bother with disruprion until I can see the rift is at 2-5% health. then, and only then do I interact with it and close it. Waste of time and DPS to fiddle around with disruptions when I'm overpowered for the enemies that come out anyway. Blackwall FTW!!

Comment: @Cherubel Why did you rollback an edit that improved grammar?